# What is the benefit of using only the 'Controller' part of MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, rest, dotnetnuke, llblgenpro

What possible benefits can one derive by using only the controller part of MVC in a service oriented architecture pattern. The database access layer, created by LLBLGen Pro, is manipulated without using the MVC ***'model'***. And, as we've been using DNN as my content management system, We've created modules that make a call via the ***'controller'*** to the service (REST based). My question is - that we could have done this the simpler way! **Why use MVC? Is it a common practice to use MVC this way?**

Comment: maybe webapi would be a better fit

Comment: @DanielPowell - Elaborate please.

Comment: webapi doesnt use views, its just a way to create a restful-ish endpoint that will be consumed by others (put simply), its essentially the M and the C from MVC

Comment: @DanielPowell - That's precisely what we're doing here. My real question is 'Why not WCF?'

Comment: @MontyPython WCF is more inclined to create services based on SOAP based protocol